# does WSL (Windows Subsystem of Linux) have a path length limit?

Tags: windows

I'm using the "Xilinx Vivado" software under windows 10,  When I run this tool, it generates a warning that tells me that Windows OS has a path length limit, and that it might not work.

So, I try to solve this problem by reinstalling the "Xilinx Vivado" software under Linux using WSL (windows subsystem for Linux), I choose the ubuntu.appx to install WSL under windows 10, now  when I run Xilinx Vivado again under linux it still gives me the same warning about windows OS having a file path length limit.  Example message from WSL-ubuntu-linux:

```
    WARNING: [BD 41-1753] The name 'gig_ethernet_pcs_pma_0_clocking_cp1' 
    you have specified is long. The  Windows OS has path length limitations. 
    It is recommended you use shorter names(less than 25 
    characters) to reduce the likelihood of issues when/if running on windows OS.
```

This makes me wonder, does Ubuntu running on top of WSL have the same file path limit as Windows 10?  I mean, WSL is built on top of windows 10, right??  so maybe it has the same file path length problems as regular windows?  Or is this just a bogus warning to let people know they should be nice to windows 10 users when running the tool under linux?  As in, don't make your file path too long because you will crash windows 10 users?